# Need recommendation for best method to create three VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, vpc

I need to build a cloudformation template to recreate three VPCs, train, hotfix and stage. I have built templates for individual VPCs, however since these three VPCs will need to be rebuilt together at the same time I am wondering what the best method is to accomplish my end goal. One template for each VPC, one template parameterized and using conditions to create each one depending on the input. Any examples of creating multiple VPCs in one template or similar would be appreciated. For context, I am rather new to building cloudformation templates.

I have built templates that create one VPC at a time, and looked at using parameters, conditions and condition functions, however I am not quite understanding how to best put all it together.

Comment: One of the nice things about this is that the configuration of each VPC might actually be almost identical, with the exception of the VPC name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the same basic architecture for all 3 vpcs,  then one template, with only the minimum number of parameters. Then create 3 stacks, each from the same template. Call each stack using the environment name eg vpc-hotfix etc.